# Silverstripe 4 large Files in Uploadfield

Tags: file-upload, silverstripe-4

when uploading a large file with uploadfield i get the error.

"Server responded with an error.
Expected a value of type "Int" but received: 4008021167"

to set the allowed filesize i used $upload->getValidator()->setAllowedMaxFileSize(6291456000);
$upload is an UploadField.

every file larger than 2gb gets this error. smaller files are uploaded without any error.

where can i adjust that i can upload bigger files.
I remember that there has been a 2GB border in the past, but i don't know where to adjust it

thanks for your answers

klaus

Answer (score 0):

The regular file upload limits don't seem to be the issue, if you are already at 2 GB. This might be the memory limit of the process itself. I would recommend looking into chunked uploads - this allows you processing larger files.

Answer (score 0):

I know, this answer is late - but the problem is rooted in the graphQL type definition of the `File` type (it is set to `Int`). I've submitted a  [pull request](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-asset-admin/pull/1299) to the upstream repository. Also here is the sed one-liner to patch it:

`sed -i 's/size\: Int/size\: Float/g' vendor/silverstripe/asset-admin/_graphql/types/File.yml`